# Where is the keybinding located in dconf for <Super>v for Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, shortcut-keys, notification-area

Pressing the key combination, `<Super>v`, will open the notification tray at the top of the screen.

I intend to override this key combination but can't seem to find where it's located in `gsettings` or in `dconf`.

For example, I'd love to remove the keybinding like this: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/notificationTray "['']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the system keyboard shortcuts..

[image]

The gsettings thing is

```
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray ['<Super>v', '<Super>m']
```

to remove the binding Super+V you can run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray "['<Super>m']"
```

for dconf way..

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/keybindings/toggle-message-tray "['<Super>m']"
```

for resetting to default

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/shell/keybindings/toggle-message-tray
```

Comment: Thanks a lot PRATAP, for the life of me I couldn't find the setting.